# Reading files with code value pairs

Tags: java, algorithm, file

I have a text file with about a hundred code value pairs [`$code`, `Value`].

For example:

Sample file

```
$codeA
valueOfA
$codeB
valueofB
.
.
.
```

These values need to be initiated into `textField`s, `radioButton`s, `checkBox`es, etc over "several panels" contained within a main Controller panel. I switch between panels through a simple card layout.

I read through the lines and use `if`/`else` statements to get values for the fields, which isn't efficient. I was wondering if there is a better approach, a more elegant approach maybe.

```
    /*
 * read File
 */
private void readFile() {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.equals("$codeA")) {
                panel1.txtFieldA.setText(br.readLine()));
            } else if (line.equals("$codeB")) {
                panel2.txtFieldB.setText(br.readLine()));
            }
            //.....
            //.....
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to create a mapping between a String and the textfield like ["$codeA" -> txtFieldA, ...] during the initialization process of the UI components. Then you can perform such things like: `txtFields.get(line).setText(br.readLine())`

Comment: Please note, if you want to move this to Code Review site, make sure you include all the code to be reviewed, rather than having `//.....` sections. Otherwise, it may get closed as stub code.

Answer (score 2):

Make a `Map` like this

```
Map<String, JTextField> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("$codeA", panel1.txtFieldA);
map.put("$codeB", panel2.txtFieldB);
```

and change your loop like this

```
String code = null;
while ((code = br.readLine()) != null) {
    JTextField jtf = map.get(code);
    if (jtf != null)
        jtf.setText(br.readLine());
    else
        br.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Lets say, I have a group of radio buttons, check boxes. Can I just declare a hashmap of a generic object

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a better solution. I welcome critique.

```
    Map<String, Operate> map = map = new HashMap<String, Operate>();
    map.put("$codeA", new TextFieldsOp(textField1));
    map.put("$codeB", new TextFieldsOp(textField2));
    map.put("$codeD", new RadBtnsOp(btnGroup));
```

Operate is an interface which is implemented by classes TextFieldsOp and RadBtnsOp.

```
public class TextFieldsOp implements Operate {

private JTextField txtF = null;

public TextFieldsOp(JTextField txtF) {
    this.txtF = txtF;
}

@Override
public void execute(String str) {
    txtF.setText(str);
  }
}
```

...

```
public class RadBtnsOp implements Operate {

ButtonGroup btnGroup;

public RadBtnsOp(ButtonGroup btnGroup) {
    this.btnGroup = btnGroup;
}

@Override
public void execute(String str) {
       //set Radio Buttons here
   }
}
```

...

```
    /*
 * read File
 */
private void readFile() {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String code = null;
        while ((code = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Operate c = map.get(code);
            if (c != null) {
                c.execute(br.readLine());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```